# My code is not passing codewar test

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a CodeWar problem:

The new "Avengers" movie has just been released! There are a lot of people at the cinema box office standing in a huge line. Each of them has a single 100, 50 or 25 dollars bill. A "Avengers" ticket costs 25 dollars.

Vasya is currently working as a clerk. He wants to sell a ticket to every single person in this line.

Can Vasya sell a ticket to each person and give the change if he initially has no money and sells the tickets strictly in the order people follow in the line?

Return YES, if Vasya can sell a ticket to each person and give the change. Otherwise, return NO.

#### Examples:

// === JavaScript ==

> tickets([25, 25, 50]) => YES
>
> tickets([25, 100]) => NO. Vasya will not have enough money to give change to 100 dollars

I have written my code and run the test but my code did not pass all test and there are some failed test but I could not figure out where I did wrong and need someone to point it out where I did wrong, below is my code....Thanks

I created an empty total variable to store all the ticket money and this variable is used to compare with the change giving out (var diff) and accumulating as well.

```js
function tickets(arr) {
  var len = arr.length;
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var diff = arr[i] - 25;
    if (diff > total) {
      return "NO"
    } else {
      total += 25;
    }
  }
  return "YES"
}
console.log(tickets([25, 25, 50]));
console.log(tickets([25, 100]));
```

Comment: Appears be to working just fine. Which part isn't functioning for you? Unless you mean it isn't keeping the cashiers till float when you make a second call to the function but that would be because you over write `total` each time the `tickets()` function is called.

Comment: I tested the code with some samples and it works, but the code did not pass the codewars test and it did not say where it went wrong.

Comment: is my code too simple to solve this problem? maybe there is more to it as I checked someone else solution, their code is so much more complicated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/a8nb8ppm/) might be easier for you? I have set the variable names to make things easier to understand. Unless you want to keep the `returns` you can simply use this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/whnjjqbe/) same method but will call a `purchase` function.

Comment: Your code is to simple - for the input `tickets([25,50,50])` it should print `NO`, since Vasya has only a 50 dollar bill and can't give change for another 50 dollar bill.

Comment: yes, agreed. Thank you for comments back and I think I will need to create a obj to store and count the three kinds of bills.